# What happens to cards after an action is resolved?

Tags: actions, ki-khanga

What happens to the cards played, and the cards still in hand if any, after an action has been resolved in Ki Khanga? Are played cards shuffled back into the deck or set aside? Do you get to keep cards still in your hand and play them on your next action?